# Vector properties with multiplication

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

> Let $a,b,c \in \Bbb R^3$ such that $a \cdot c = 1$ and $a \cdot b = −1$. Show that
>   $a \times ( b \times c) =  b + c$.

I tried to substitute in $a = (1,0,0)$, $b = (1,0,0)$, $c = (-1,0,0)$ but it didn't work. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is "$\times$" the [cross product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product)? Then what are "$1$" and "$-1$"?

Comment: No I don't think so. I edit again.

Comment: What is "$*$" now? If it were the dot product then $a*(b*c)=1$ doesn't make sense.

Comment: a,b,c are vectors that is just what is in my textbook.

Comment: @Bye_World I put something rong. Pitcher add.

Comment: @buzzedChainSaw Have you seen the identity $A\times (B\times C) = (A\cdot C)B-(A\cdot B)C$ (the so-called "BAC-CAB" rule) before?

Answer (score 0):

Hint: use the [vector triple product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triple_product#Vector_triple_product) formula $a \times (b \times c) = b (a \cdot c) - c (a \cdot b)$.

Answer (score 0):

> > > Let $a,b,c \in \Bbb R^3$ such that $a \cdot c = 1$ and $a \cdot b = −1$. Show that
> > >       $a \times ( b \times c) =  b + c$.
>
> I tried to substitute in $a = (1,0,0)$, $b = (1,0,0)$, $c = (-1,0,0)$ but it didn't work. What am I doing wrong?

You have $a\cdot c= -1$ and $a\cdot b=1$